# Why using wp_send_json() resolves my issue when previously using json_encode response?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, jsonencoder

I wrote a PHP class to process a CSV file and upload entries. The last round was over 15,000+ row in the file.

Previously, in my wrapper I would return the json response like so:

```
echo json_encode($jsonResponse);
wp_die();
```

That worked fine when we were uploading files that had up to 2,000 rows. Recently, we uploaded a file that had 4,000+ rows and the json response never would print - `response` would be `NULL`. After many hours of checking if the file itself was causing the issue, I elected to use the following

```
wp_send_json($jsonResponse);
```

And my response would show to the screen as expected. I've looked into the `wp_send_json()` method and understand it is the expected usage for WP. My question is why did my previous implementation work up to now? I'm assuming the response being ran through manual `json_encode()` was too large?

I'm looking for insight into the root of the problem here, and a deeper understanding of why my solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

I make an assumption that in your case `json_encode()` returns boolean `false`. `json_encode()` never returns `null`, it returns either a string or `false` on error. It can, of course, return a string "`null`", but never "`NULL`".

Most likely your data contains some binary data (e.g. broken UTF-8), which a valid JSON must not contain. You can check the actual error message by calling `json_last_error_msg()` after `json_encode()`.

`wp_send_json()` performs some sanitization against your data, making it json-encodable. But even though it does produce some nice JSON output, the data is effectively "broken" (whether noticeably or not) because the sanitization process modifies the data.